# battery monitor cell measurement

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, batteries

I'm making a project witch contains a battery monitor, the battery has 20 li-po cells in series (84v 60Ah). Now, i studied a lot of battery charges (like icharger 4010 duo) in order to see how they measure the cells, the most common way i found is to use voltage dividers on the input from cells, then a pair of multiplexers then op amp buffers, then differential op amp, then gain op amp. Then in my application fed in to an AVR 10 bit ADC with 5v reff. I made a simplified schematic showing the concept. The resistors will be 0.1% tolerance, and the op amp tl274 in order to keep error am small as possible, but still my concern is that i might not get an 10mV accuracy, because 10 0.1% tolerance resistors in the measurement chain plus gain of 11.
Somehow for chargers this solution works but i don quite get how the get 10mV accuracy.
One way to improve accuracy is to measure and select the resistors to be very close to the needed value. 
The problem noise is filtered in the SW.
So any opinions on the circuit presented might be helpful.

Thank you. 
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for why this circuit may or may not meet the accuracy goals?

Comment: there appears to be a problem with your circuit.  ... please include all the batteries in the schematic diagram

Comment: There are IC's which perform many of the functions you need. TI calls them "analog front ends," and Linear calls them "battery stack monitors," but they perform very similar functions. There is a lot to this. I think it will be VERY challenging to do a single stack of 20 cells. You may consider breaking it up into two stacks of 10. The FET's still need to be rated for over 84 V, though, because once one of them opens, that is what the voltage will be across the open FET.

Comment: Yes, i'm  looking for why this circuit may or may not meet the accuracy goals, and if the components specified op amp performance and input resistor 1M/100K might be too high value and not have good enough tolerance 0.1% . I try to stay off dedicated chips they communicate on serial (i don't have any free comms any more) are expensive and hard to find, and again if there are chargers that work very well on this simple technology this is why i'm trying this option.

Comment: How do you plan to make up for the imbalance created by monitoring each cell with a voltage divider?

Comment: Also, what are you actually making? A charger?

Comment: well i have 2 options to make up for the imbalance created by monitoring each cell with a voltage divider, one is to manually select and measure the resistors and the second is calibration in the SW.

Comment: but the big issue is that the error gets bigger from the first to last cell. Lets say for cell 20: with 0.1% tolerance i get the 1M resistor to be 1.001M and the 100K to be 99.9k, and for cell 19  i get the 1M resistor to be 0.999M and the 100K to be 100.1k, the error for difference between 84v (cell20) and 79.8(cell19) will be 300mV, but for difference between cell 2(8.4v) and cell1(4.2v) with same resistor difference the error is only 30mV, so SW calibration will be difficult to get right, so i wonder how is it done in those chargers witch use resistor dividers.

Comment: i'm making an ESC for BLDC motor (25Kw), but the same principle i'l use when later i'l make the charger.

Comment: Although calibration in SW might be easier than in HW

Comment: What are you going to do with the individual cell voltage information? I am trying to see if there is a solution that does not involve measuring all the cell voltages in a central location. Some BMS's use a single balancing IC on each cell.

Comment: All the cells voltages will be displayed on LCD, data logged, and calculate cell health, and system takes actions according to cell state, and so on...

Comment: OK. Well, good luck.

Comment: Your design is wrong. The voltage on any analog input should not be larger than the Vcc of the 74HC4067. But the the maximum voltage behind the devider resistors 10:1 is 8.4 V, this is too much for an IC with Vcc = 5V Vi_max is 5.5 V. To monitor a stack of 20 cells, you need more than 16 analog inputs.

Comment: The circuit is not complete in practice it has another pair of 74hc4067 and yes thanks for mentioning about the supply i almost forgot i'l have to power them from 10v  max supply for 74hc4067 is 11v. Until now they were powered from 5v and i only tested with 10 cells witch si 42v and after voltage deviders i got max 4.2v witch was fine. Thanks

Comment: O i forgot the division is by 11 (1M and 100K) not 10 so 84 gets 7. 636

Answer (score 1):

well i made the circuit for testing, there was a mistake in the schematic the differential op amp the inputs are the other way around + to - and - to +, i got 1% tolerance resistors and in reality they are not that bad in tolerance witch means 0.1% will be even better. Now i test it and see how well it works.
This is the updated schemastic[image]

Comment: well, circuit work's, in the SW a few tricks are needed in order to work properly, it does a fine job.  there is no need for c1 (100nF) it causes problems.